# Using a Eigen Matrix Ref in a class combning with Odeint

Tags: c++, matrix, reference, eigen, odeint

I wanted to use odeint to solve a set of coupled differential equations for complex Eigen Matrices adaptively, the first idea was to just use a Vector of Matrices(not working due to assumptions made in the error estimator). 
Now I try to build a workaround by using a big matrix and creating Eigen::Refs to blocks of the Matrix, but that doesn't work because Refs do not have a default constructor. 
Also in the handling of the refs, is there any difference between them or matrices? This is because I have to rearrange the components of the matrix later on.

Minimal code example:
in .h:

```
class example{
public:
    example(int&);
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXcd> vertex_P_zero;
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXcd> vertex_D_zero;
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXcd> vertex_X_zero;
private: 
    Eigen::MatrixXcd Vertex_channels;
```

and in the .cpp:

```
example::example(int &_mat_size){
    Vertex_channels = Eigen::MatrixXcd::Zero(3*_mat_size, _mat_size);
    vertex_P_zero = (Vertex_channels.block(0,0,_mat_size*bond_num, _mat_size*bond_num));
    vertex_X_zero = (Vertex_channels.block(_mat_size*bond_num, 0,_mat_size*bond_num,  _mat_size*bond_num));
    vertex_D_zero = (Vertex_channels.block(2*_mat_size*bond_num, 0,_mat_size*bond_num, _mat_size*bond_num));
}
```

Do I understand right that when passing the refs to functions I pass them as Ref and can access their elements like for matrices?

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

For the initialization, you can write:

```
example::example(int _mat_size)
    : Vertex_channels(3*_mat_size*bond_num,3*_mat_size),
      vertex_P_zero(Vertex_channels.block(0,0,_mat_size*bond_num, _mat_size*bond_num)),
      vertex_X_zero(Vertex_channels.block(_mat_size*bond_num, 0,_mat_size*bond_num,  _mat_size*bond_num)),
      vertex_D_zero(Vertex_channels.block(2*_mat_size*bond_num, 0,_mat_size*bond_num, _mat_size*bond_num))
{
    Vertex_channels.setZero();
}
```

then, you can indeed read/write `vertex_X_zero` and the others just like a `MatrixXcd`, and modifying an entry of `vertex_X_zero` will modify `Vertex_channels`, and vice-versa. Of course, if you pass `vertex_P_zero` to a function expecting a `MatrixXcd`, then a copy will occur. Your function must either be templated, or written to take a `Ref<MatrixXcd>`.

Comment: Thank you very much ggael :)  In the meantime I was able to get it working in both ways, with vectors and with refs ^^, thanks to your help.